# wordpress　カテゴリー毎の一覧ベージへのリンクについて

Tags: php, wordpress

wordpressでオリジナルテーマを作成中です。
カテゴリー別の記事一覧へのリンクを作っていますが、NotFoundになるかトップページが表示されてしまいます。

カテゴリーは管理画面にてHTML(ID=2)、CSS(ID=3)、Javascript(ID=4)を作りました。

wordpress codexより
`<a href="/index.php?cat=７">カテゴリーのタイトル</a>`
とあったので、HTMLのカテゴリーへのリンクを
`<a href="/index.php?cat=2">HTML</a>`
と記載するとNot Found
またパーマリンクを使用し
`<a href="/index.php/categories/html/">HTML</a>`
としてもNot Found

```
<?php
    $category_id = get_cat_ID( 'html' );
    $category_link = get_category_link( $category_id );
?>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $category_link ); ?>" title="html">HTML</a>
```

カテゴリーIDを取得し、カテゴリーアーカイブページのURLを戻り値としましたが、こちらはトップページに飛んでしまいます。カーソルを合わせるとURLにID=２とあったので、取得は出来ていると思うのですが。

```
<?php
$cat = get_the_category();
$catId = $cat[0]->cat_ID;
$catName = $cat[0]->name;
$catSlug = $cat[0]->category_nicename;
$link = get_category_link($catId);
?>
<a href="<?php echo $link ?>" title="<?php echo $catName; ?>"><?php echo $catName; ?></a>
```

カテゴリー情報を取得してそれらを出力させてリンクを作ってみましたが、こちらもトップページに飛んでしまいます。

私事ですが、3月からプログラミングの勉強を始めた初心者で、
https://ichimaruni-design.com/2015/07/wordpress-wp/
を参考にし進めております

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: a. 管理画面の「投稿」→「カテゴリ」で、作成済みのカテゴリにマウスオーバーすると、 `編集 | クイック編集 | 削除 | 表示` の様なリンクが表示されると思うのですが、その中の「表示」の部分の URL を確認してみてください。
b. オリジナルテーマに `archive.php` や `category.php` は含まれていますか？ URL はカテゴリーアーカイブページを示しているのに、表示がトップページになってしまっている場合、 `archive.php` が見つからず、代替として `index.php` が表示されている可能性があります。
https://wphierarchy.com

Comment: @emus 様　ありがとうございます。表示部分のURLは合っているのですが、archive.phpとcategory.phpは作成しておりませんでした。テンプレート階層についても理解が足りなかったです。そのPHPファイルを作成して実行してみて、また改めてコメントさせていただきます！

Comment: @emus 様　ご連絡が遅くなってしまい申し訳ありません。おっしゃる通り、category.phpを作成していなかった為、カテゴリー毎にページを表示したいのに見つからず、index.phpが表示されていたようです。category.phpを作成してみたところ、それぞれのカテゴリーページが表示されました！非常に助かりました。ありがとうございました。